# Swift - UICollection snap back too fast if item scrolled a little

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make UICollectionView snap back to the center of any item cell near to it,
But the problem is when i move it slightly a little bit it snaps back too fast to the center of the cell which is not looking smooth, 
Is it possible to ignore or disable scroll unless the user is swiping to the next item and not make scrollview snaps it the same item ?

here's my code for snapping

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let cellWidthIncludingSpacing = layout.itemSize.width + layout.minimumLineSpacing
    var offset = targetContentOffset.pointee

    let index = (offset.x + scrollView.contentInset.left ) / cellWidthIncludingSpacing
    let roundedIndex = round(index)

    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    offset = CGPoint(x: roundedIndex * cellWidthIncludingSpacing - scrollView.contentInset.left, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)

    targetContentOffset.pointee = offset


}
```

Edit: 
This is how it snaps back from physical device. 
it's here slower because it's gif

[image]

Comment: Have you tested this on an actual device with an actual finger as input "device" - it may feel more correct if you have a finger instead of a mouse.

Comment: @luk2302 yes i did and it's still snaps back very fast kinda look like laggy also keep in mind that i'm using UIScrollView.DecelerationRate.fast

Comment: I think you will have better control by updating UICollectionViewFlowLayout, a good example to do this is here: https://github.com/lukagabric/LGLinearFlow

Comment: "Is it possible to ignore or disable scroll unless the user is swiping to the next item and not make scrollview snaps it the same item?” ... so if the user starts a gesture, say having only dragged one cm so far, are you saying that you don’t want it to move at all, giving the user no feedback at all that their gesture is being recognized? Are you saying that you don’t want drag gestures recognized at all, and only swipe gestures?

Comment: @Rob What i meant was if the user drag speed was fast gonna move to the other item, and i would really like the idea of adding swipe gesture recognizers i'm considering it if i did't get rid of that laggy snap back

Answer (score 0):

Its snapping back because you are directly setting the contentOffset.  Instead you should call the UIScrollViewMethod [setContentOffset(_:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619400-setcontentoffset) with animated being true.  If you still do not like the results then consider instead implementing the UICollectionLayout method [targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617729-targetcontentoffsetforproposedco?language=objc) and then the layout will automatically snap to the point you return.

Comment: I tried setContentOffset(_:animated:) in the same code above it's weird sometimes it snaps to the center of the item and sometime it does nothing, the targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity: i used the same code above but returning the offset and replace each scrollView with collectionView and targetContentOffset.pointee with collectionView.contentOffset, But it seems like i'm doing something wrong because it's not doing anything

Comment: you implemented scrollViewWillEndDragging which is not the same as targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity:  . In scrollViewWillEndDragging you set the offset manually and unanimated.  If you return the proposed offset in targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity: the collection view will decelerate and animate to the position you return.

Answer (score 0):

In case after 3 years someone's still facing this problem :)

For a fast workaround you can look at the velocity value in `func scrollViewWillEndDragging`. Empirically found that it snaps too fast if the velocity absolute value is less than 1.4 (in my case). So if it's less I set `targetContentOffset.pointee` to current offset and use `scrollView.setContentOffset` animated, if not – alter `targetContentOffset.pointee`.

Here is the code:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(
    _ scrollView: UIScrollView,
    withVelocity velocity: CGPoint,
    targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>
) {
    // Using Decimal to avoid calculation imprecisions
    let decItemWidthWithSpacing = Decimal(itemWidth + interItemSpacing)
    let decTargetOffset = Decimal(targetContentOffset.pointee.x)
    var pageIndexNotRounded = decTargetOffset / decItemWidthWithSpacing
    var pageIndex = Decimal()
    NSDecimalRound(&pageIndex, &pageIndexNotRounded, 0, .plain)

    let newTargetOffsetX = CGFloat(exactly: pageIndex * decItemWidthWithSpacing as NSNumber) ?? 0

    if abs(velocity.x) < 1.4 {
        targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: newTargetOffsetX, y: 0), animated: true)
    } else {
        targetContentOffset.pointee.x = newTargetOffsetX
    }
}
```